# Get context from UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

Can I get the context (`CGContextRef`) from exists `UIImageView`?

Detail: I have a controller link to xib file. In IB I have added a `UIImageView` and reference its on:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

Now, in `viewDidLoad` How get the `UIImageView`  context (`CGContextRef`)?

Before this, If I use:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

output:

```
<Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context
```

suggest?

Comment: What do you want to DO with the context? Contexts are only valid when you create them yourself, or within the (sorry) context of a drawRect: call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use your own drawing methods you should apply them in the drawRect: method of the UIView. You need to subclass UIView to create your own drawing logic: In XCode use File->New File and select UIView as a template which will give you the basic framework. In Interface-Builder you can first add a new view and then set it use your class under Identity Tab in the Inspector window.

The method should then start with something like this to give you a reference to the context:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)fr {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    ... DRAWING CODE ...
}
```

This methods automatically gets called when the view is first displayed. If your logic depends on some variables you should call `setNeedsDisplay` on the UIView to let the view re-run the drawing logic.

However, this will not work on `UIImageView` ([LINK](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/UIImageView_Class.pdf)):

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> ***Special Considerations***
>
> The UIImageView class is optimized to draw its images to the display. UIImageView will not call drawRect: a subclass. If your subclass needs custom drawing code, it is recommended you use UIView as the base class.

Answer (score 2):

Add a call to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size); before UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 It will work.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size); 
 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```