# draw a square border in middle of screen

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to draw a transparent square (border only) in the middle of a view, but I'm getting a really hard time to find out how. I think I have two problems, the first one is about draw a transparent square with black borders, the second one is about to put it in the middle of the view.

Is there any good tutorials to follow?

**UPDATE**

I have tried to follow Apple tutorials and I have a piece of code to draw a rectangle inside my view controller:

```
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(60,170,200,80);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

But I can't find how to add it to a specific view, or to the center of the view.

Comment: doesn't developer.apple.com have good information on cocos2d?

Comment: does this answer your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745710/get-context-from-uiimageview

Comment: or : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687642/problem-in-draw-rect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you probably want to subclass the UIView in question and override its drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

be sure to call:

```
[super drawRect:rect];
```

Then you want to use coordinates in your drawing code that are relative to the size of the view you are drawing in.

So you get something more like:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGFloat width = 200;
    CGFloat height = 80;
    CGFloat x = (self.frame.size.width - width) * 0.5f;
    CGFloat y = (self.frame.size.height - height) * 0.5f;
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The drawing code you provided needs to be placed in a custom UIView subclass in it's drawRect method.

But if you're just trying to show a rectangle somewhere on the screen, it would be easier to just add a subview of the desired size and set its layer properties accordingly:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
//...
UIView *rectView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60,170,200,80)];
rectView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
rectView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
rectView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
[someView addSubview:rectView];
```